# The content in email not rendered as standard HTML

Tags: django

I wrote the `password_reset_email.html` as

```
<p>
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at JoCo. <br>
<br>
Please go to the following page and choose a new password: <br>

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'user:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{# {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/user/reset/{{ uid }}/{{ token }} #}
<br>
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.get_username }}
<br>

Thanks for using our site!". <br>
```

When I checked it within email, found it not rendered:

[image]

I employed the `PasswordResetView` [django/forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py)

How to enable email content displayed as standard HTML?

Comment: you are missing the `<html>` and `<body>` tag, aren't you ?

Comment: Can you show us the code that renders the template and creates/sends the email?

Comment: I tried, it display <html> and <body> tags. @Pac0

Comment: actually, the rendering would also depend on your *email client* anyway.

Comment: as manassehkatz asked, you should provide more context. Maybe you are creating an html with the tags `<p>` and `<br>` embedded as *text* inside a real html file (that we are not seeing fully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as already said in comments, you need to enclose your html code in `<html></html>` and `<body></body>` tags for this to be valid html.

Second, have you actually tried to send this html code as an email ? HTML is just text actually, with the proper syntax. The *rendering* would be the sole job of the email client.

If yes, I suggest you to check the source of the email, to check what was really sent to your client. What could happen :

1) Your client is just not rendering HTML, because of capabilities or configurations.

2) You actually have an html file, with somehow your "HTML code" embedded and encoded as text content of a really rendered HTML file. (with your `<p>` as `&lt;p&gt;` for instance)